# To show continuity of a inverse distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let work with the space where distributions and its inverses exist. For any distribution $F$ its inverse for any $p\in(0,1)$ is $F^{-1}(p)=\inf \{t\in \mathbb{R} : F(t) \geq p \}.$

Continuity definition: For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that the following holds $$\forall x~|F(x)-G(x)|\leq\delta \implies |F^{-1}(p)-G^{-1}(p)| \leq \epsilon $$ for some $p\in(0,1)$.

I am not able to characterize the distance between inverse function assuming the distributions to be close. Any hints to solve this?

My try:

We can have $F(x)=1_{x\geq 0}$ and $G(x)=(1-\delta) 1_{x\geq 0} + \delta 1_{x\geq 1}$. This ensures $\sup_x |F(x)-G(x)| \leq \delta$. But for some $p\in(1-\delta,1)$ we have $F^{-1}(p)=0$ and $G^{-1}(p)=1$ which says $|F^{-1}(p)-G^{-1}(p)|=1.$

So, does this suffice to say that $F^{-1}$ is not satisfying this continuity? I am having trouble with the negative of this statement.

Comment: You have to state your assumptions properly. Are $F$ and $G$ distributions in the sense of Probability Theory? Are they assumed to have an inverse? One can say that your statement is false simply because distribution functions need not have an inverse. Also, you are expected to show some effort on your part.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Let's suppose inverse exists. Thank you, I've now provided what I've until now, any help is appreciated!

Comment: $1_{x=0}$ is not a distribution function. Do you mean $1_{x\geq 0}$? Besides this function does not have an inverse.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected that. I've defined the inverse function now, sorry for not doing it earlier! Now, what do you think of this counterexample?